# Larry and Laura Literal

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

Larry Literal loved Laura Literal, his lovely long-suffering wife. They'd lived together as husband and wife 50 long years. Longing to live near long-lost loved ones, they'd recently re-located to a new home near a baseball stadium. Larry loudly lamented the lousy mini-blinds that let in the blinding stadium lights each night. On Larry's 77th birthday, Laura left for the local home-goods store. Lounging in a lime-green leather chair, Larry logged into his streaming service and binged black-and-white gangster movies--lately Larry LOVED black-and-white gangster movies! When Laura returned hours later, Larry met her at the car, longing to learn of her new purchase. Laura stood there, a long, shrouded unknown item under her arm. Larry blurted "What's that?”. Laura answered him. Larry screamed, dashed inside, locked the door, and called the police. Laura stood there dumbfounded. What was wrong with him? She looked down at the new curtains that she still held in her arms, and puzzled.

What on earth could Laura have said to make Larry act this way? It has nothing to do with all the L's in the story.

**Hint 1:**

> Larry's name fits him like a glove: he is literal to a fault.

**Hint 2:**

> It has something to do with what Laura bought AND with Larry’s recent movie fascination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Larry Literal believed that his wife

> was about to kill him: her response to his question was *"It's curtains for you!"*

Comment: A bit weird that since this is an idiom, it can't be literal. But okay.

Comment: Yeah—I debated on calling it literal, but in the end V guvax gur vqvbz vgfrys shaqnzragnyyl vfa’g yvgreny, naq uvf gnxvat guvatf yvgrenyyl jnf uvf zvfgnxr.